# Search database using partially correct user input

Tags: sql, database, sql-like

We have a table in a database that contains products. Users can search on the product name. This was implemented in the following simple way:

1. Before going to the database: `input = input.toLowerCase() + "%"`
2. The query: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE lower(name) LIKE input`

We discovered this doesn't work for some names because users don't type them exactly. For example, the product with name `Sally's Déjà Vu` would constantly get mistypes as:

- `sally` or `sallys` instead of `sally's`
- `deja vu` or `dejavu` instead of `déjà vu`

A possible solution we are investigating is to create an additional database column called "simple_name" that instead of holding the exact name contains only letters from a-z, for example: `sallysdejavu`. This column can be indexed. We would then adapt the search in the following way:

1. Before going to the database: `input = input.toLowerCase() + %`
2. `input = input.replaceAllNonLettersWithPercentageSign()`
3. The query: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE simple_name LIKE input`

We are contemplating the impact of this change:

- Extra storage size necessary
- No need for the lower() operation in the query
- The input might contain many %'s (e.g.: `sally%s%d%j%a%vu`)

Any thoughts on this approach? Does it make sense to have a preformatted, optimized column table to perform searches on? What is the impact of having complex like statements with many %'s.

Comment: Look into `soundex` like functions.  If your SQL engine does not have one or one appropriate for the given language, you can possibly write your own.

Comment: Interesting function. I'm not sure if this can be made to work for partial input (e.g.: the user only types the firt 4 letters of the product name and wants to see intermediate results)

Comment: Actually `soundex` works best when matching the first few characters.  It does not help for matching internal characters.